# For loop in R through data.frame

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have the following data.frame

```
Name<-c("Jack","Jerry","Emma","Andy","Jayde","Lynn","Liam")
Education<-c("Master","Master","Master","Bach","Bach","PhD","PhD")
Salary<-c(20000,20000,20000,30000,10000,70000,70000)
People<-data.frame(Name,Education,Salary)
```

I now have to use a for loop (silly, I know) that will loop through the frame, find the "education" level, and add a salary increase.

how can this be done?

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: an increase in salary for "Bach" by 1000, "Master" by 2000, "PhD" by 3000

Comment: i do have a function that add this desired amounts to the salary using if/else that works fine, but the second part of this requires a for loop

Comment: You could potentially write a line for each education level. For example, here's for `Phd`: `People[People$Education == "PhD", "Salary"] <- People[People$Education == "PhD", "Salary"] + 3e3` and so on.

Comment: not sure i follow: would this be instead of the data.frame?

Comment: I have no idea what you asking. It will just replace the for loop.

Comment: oh, i see. yes this work great. however, I am required to use a for loop.

Comment: Why are you required to use a for loop? And if so, what is the question?

Comment: i need to loop through the data.frame (People) using a for loop and making the necessary additions to the salaries. i know this is inefficient, but this is what is required.

Comment: Then I can't help you, sorry. I forgot how to write `for` loops.

Comment: People$Salary<-ifelse(People$Education==x,People$Salary+y,People$Salary)  , I don't see why a statement like this isn't satisfying to do the trick for you? Why you need a for loop ?

Comment: I think this is some sort of exercise; "Write a for loop to run through the dataframe and add 1000 to bachelors, 2000 to masters...".

Comment: it is an assignment for a stats class, yes. i have been able to do this many different ways, but can not figure how to use a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it would be better to do as mentioned in the comments, you can do it the ugly way:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(People)) {
  if (People$Education[i] == "Bach") {
    People$Salary[i] <- People$Salary[i]+1000
  } else if (People$Education[i] == "Master") {
    People$Salary[i] <- People$Salary[i]+2000
  } else {
    People$Salary[i] <- People$Salary[i]+3000
  }
}
```

Comment: PERFECT! Ugly indeed.

Comment: Don't think you need last `else if`. It probably can be just a simple  `else` without any condition.

Comment: Fair enough, I can make it less-bad.

Comment: Another way would be to add `1000` to all salaries and then loop only on `Master` and `Phd` while adding `1000` and `2000` respectively